# Hidden Control value is not correct when read in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a Hidden Control in a nested gridview to determine if it is expanded or not. I set the value in the javascript function.  It is being set correctly because of alerts that I have set.  In the RowDataBound method, I want to read the Hidden control to determine if I should expand the grid or not.  When I read the value in the RowDataBound method, it is always '0'.
My markup is huge so this is only the nested grid, UpdatePanel and hiddencontrol association:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnlNestedGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="div<%# Eval("GroupID") %>" style="display:none">                      
<asp:GridView ID="GroupMemberGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="GroupMemberGridView_RowDeleting" 
 OnRowCommand="GroupMemberGridView_RowCommand" CssClass="grid" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5"
  onpageindexchanging="GroupMemberGridView_PageIndexChanging" onpageindexchanged="GroupMemberGridView_PageIndexChanged">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MemberID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="mggvLblMemberID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberID") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Member Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"> 
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="mggvLblMemberName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberName") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>               
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="mggvDDLMemberName" runat="server" 
               class="chosen-single" data-placeholder="Choose member…">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqValueDDLMemberInsert" runat="server" InitialValue="0" 
                    ControlToValidate="mggvDDLMemberName" 
                    ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active Device(s)">                   
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="mggvLblActiveDevice" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("ActiveDevice").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>                   
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="mggvDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
                Text="Delete" CssClass="gridActionbutton"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Group Member?')" >
            </asp:Button>
        </ItemTemplate>                                     
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="mggvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Member" Width="90%" 
                CssClass="gridActionbutton"/> 
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>      
<asp:HiddenField ID="mggvIsExpanded" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="0" />
```

This is the javascript function that expands/collapses the grid and sets the hidden value:

```
 function DivExpandCollapse(groupID) {    
    var div = document.getElementById(groupID);
    var img = document.getElementById('img' + groupID);
    //alert shows correct hidden value
     alert($(div).parent().siblings("input:hidden[id$='mggvIsExpanded']").val());
    if (div.style.display == "none") {               
        div.style.display = "inline";
        img.src = "Images/minus.png";
        $(div).parent().siblings("input:hidden[id$='mggvIsExpanded']").val("1");   
        $("#" + div.getAttribute('id') + ".chosen-single").chosen("destroy");
        $("#" + div.getAttribute('id') + ".chosen-single").chosen({
            search_contains: true,
            width: "100%",
            placeholder_text_single: "Choose member…",
            no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
        });         
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = "none";
        img.src = "Images/plus.png";
        $(div).parent().siblings("input:hidden[id$='mggvIsExpanded']").val("0");
    }
}
```

This is the code behind event.  I am only showing the hidden value code.:

```
protected void UserGroupGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      int tiGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(UserGroupGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
      GridView tgvGroupMember = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GroupMemberGridView");
        HiddenField hiddenExpand = (HiddenField)tgvGroupMember.Parent.FindControl("mggvIsExpanded");
        //This value is always "0" - the initial value
        String hiddenValue = hiddenExpand.Value.ToString(); 
   }
 }
```

Even though the hidden value is set in the javascript.  The value is always zero in the code behind which is the initial value.

Why is the hidden value never showing as "1" in the RowDataBound event when the grid is expanded?

**UPDATE**
I put the asp:HiddenField inside the ContentTemplate which is inside the UpdatePanel.  But it still is not reading the hidden value correctly.

Comment: your `HiddenField`  is not inside the `gridview`

Comment: The hiddenfield has to be inside the gridview?  All of the examples has it as a sibling to the UpdatePanel.

Comment: why you need `FindControl()`, why not just `mggvIsExpanded.Value`, it is a server control...

Comment: The RowDataBound event is called when the grid is being rendered. Your javascript takes place in the client browser. In other words, the javascript executes after the RowDataBound event has taken place. You would never see the results of the javascript action in the RowDataBound event since the RowDataBound event executes on the server *before* any javascript is taking place on the client.

Comment: Putting the HIddenField inside the gridview gives a parser error because a GridView does not have a public property HiddenField.

Comment: The RowDataBound event is called after any update/change.  I expand the grid and add a row to it.  After the row is added the RowDataBound event is called.  So after expanding the grid, the hidden value should be 1 and it is set.  The Add command occurs then the RowDataBound event happens.  But in the RowDataBound event the hidden value is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hidden value was being set but when I repopulated the parent grid, the hidden value was reset to 0.

I got it to work by called the javascript 'Expand' function in the 'RowCreated' event.  This occurs after the Add Command and RowDataBound events.

Works fine now.

THanks for all of the help.

Answer (score 1):

You're treating the hidden field as if it's in a newly-bound row of the GridView.

Just keep things simple and instead of referencing FindControl(), reference the control directly like by mggvIsExpanded like:

```
protected void UserGroupGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //reference mggvIsExpanded without jumping through hoops
        String hiddenValue = mggvIsExpanded.Value.ToString(); 
    }
 }
```

If the value still isn't correct, it may mean that you're trying to reference the control too early in the page lifecycle. Make sure the code runs after Page.Load or otherwise manually get the value from Request.Form["mggvIsExpanded"].

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand.  I have to put it within a  column in the asp.Grid, don't I? What does the markup look like?

Comment: No. The hidden field can be placed anywhere (and is placed outside of the grid in your markup). You can still reference it in RowDataBound even though it's outside the grid.

Comment: So I can keep the HiddenField after the UpdatePanel?

Comment: As I step thru the code, this is the order of events. On Page_Load, the grids are collapsed and the Hidden value is 0.  I expand a grid and set that Hidden value to 1. (In the javascript this is correctly set.) I add a row, goes to the RowCommand event, then to the RowDataBound event.  The hidden value is 0.

Comment: Page_Load is called on EVERY request, not just the first time the page is loaded. Try putting two breakpoints in your code. One in Page_Load, the other in UserGroupGridView_RowDataBound. When you add a row, can you confirm that Page_Load is hit before the breakpoint in UserGroupGridView_RowDataBound? Is there a value in Request.Form["mggvIsExpanded"]?

Comment: Page_Load is hit before UserGroupGridVIew_RowDataBound. The mggsIsExpanded value for the row that is expanded is 0.